# Angularjs factory http return value

Tags: angularjs, arrays, http

i've this factory thar call external api that return an array:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
 .factory('PlacesService', function($http) {
  var places = "";
  var request = $http({
    method: "get",
    url: 'http://someurl/getPlaces.php'
  });

 request.then(function (data) {
   places = data.response
 });

 console.log(places); // return empty string

 return {
   all: function() {
     return places;
   },
   get: function(placesId) {
     return places[placesId];
   }
 }
});
```

Places variable returned by http is an empty string.
If I initialize places as an array and the I use **places.push(data.response)** it works, but return an array of array.
Could you help me?

Comment: Your promise seems to be rejected, thats why your variable is still an empty string. Try this:  request.then(function (data) {
   places = data.response
 }, function(error) {console.log(error);});

Comment: No error... only empty string from console.log(places);

Comment: Hahaha, can't believe I overlooked that detail, @Todd Miller is right :)

Answer (score 2):

Your log here is outside of the context of the promise the `$http` call is returning. Basically the log gets executed before the promise is resolved, so your string is still empty when the log executes.

Comment: I had guessed it. How could i handle the promise to have right places value outside then function?

Comment: Well that depends on what you want to do with the value. A common pattern is to return the promise generated by the `$http` call so that other parts of your application will kind of halt execution until the promise is resolved. Usually I will handle this will the `resolve` property of a route - the controller won't fire until the promise is resolved, so you can be sure when you call your `all` or `get` function, `places` will have the correct values.